# grt number of matching entries in array with vanilla js

Tags: javascript

This is what i have:

```
[
 "aaaaaa",
 "aaaaaa",
 "bbb",
 "bbb",
 "bbb",
 "cccccccccccc",
 "cccccccccccc",
 "d",
]
```

how can I get the number matching entries in this array into an object. This is after I've sorted it.

This is what I need:

```
{
 "bbb": 3,
 "aaaaaa": 2
 "cccccccccccc": 2
 "d": 1
}
```

also if there's somehow a way to sort the JSON from largest to smallest, that would be great

Comment: If you even need to group/aggregate over some entries, using `reduce` is usually the solution

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to generate this object:

```js
const array = [
 "aaaaaa",
 "aaaaaa",
 "bbb",
 "bbb",
 "bbb",
 "cccccccccccc",
 "cccccccccccc",
 "d",
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: (acc[cur] || 0) + 1 }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a simple for loop:

```js
let arr = [
 "aaaaaa",
 "aaaaaa",
 "bbb",
 "bbb",
 "bbb",
 "cccccccccccc",
 "cccccccccccc",
 "d",
]

let counterItems = {}

for (let i of arr){
    counterItems[i] = 1 + (counterItems[i] || 0)
}

console.log(counterItems)
```